# Given an array of indicies to splice, generate the order in which each element was removed

Tags: algorithm

This is part of a larger program, but this is the bottleneck.

Given an array of numbers that mean "repeatedly splice the element at this index out of an array", I want to generate an array that represents the order in which each element should be spliced.

So the following:

```
[3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1]
```

means to run these operations:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
[a, b, d, e, f, g]    // 3rd element removed, c
[b, d, e, f, g]       // 1st element removed, a
[b, d, e, g]          // 4th element removed, f
[b, d, e]             // 4th element removed, g
[b, d]                // 3rd element removed, e
[d]                   // 1st element removed, b
[]                    // 1st element removed, d
```

And I want to generate (without *actually* running all of the splice operations above):

```
[2, 6, 1, 7, 5, 3, 4]
```

which is the order in which each element was removed.

Looking for a solution better than `O(N^2)`

---

Below is not part of the question, just what I'm actually doing, for anyone interested:

This is part of a seam carving implementation.  I'm generating a compressed format that represents all of the seams in a given image, and then removing those seams in the client.  Since a seam always moves 1px left or right at each step, a seam can efficiently be stored as:

```
starting index, left, right, left, left, left, right, ...
```

I then remove this seam from the image, and calculate the next one.  Storage wise it's 2 bytes + 1 bit per pixel after that, or a seam of length 1024 is stored in 130 bytes.

With respect to the original indicies, however, "left 1" and "right 1" is only accurate for the first seam.  After that any seam can cross over another seam, so "right 1", with respect to the original indicies, could mean move right 10, or even move left 10.

In other words I'm just trying to decompress this data.

Comment: I don't understand your example output. How does the column, `c, a, f, g, e, b, d`, correspond with `[2, 6, 1, 7, 5, 3, 4]`? It seems to me that it would correspond with `[3, 1, 6, 7, 5, 2, 4]`.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat -- The code here is JS, as it's running in a browser.  It's a bit hard to fully explain what's going on, as the example here is just a minified version of the problem.  The indicies are stored as (in a binary format): `[123, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, ...]`, which translated to `[123, 122, 121, 122, 121, 120, ...]`.  This is one "seam".  Then the first index of each seam creates the array that I'm talking about in my question (the `[3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1]` array) for the first row of pixels.  The 2nd index of each seam creates another array for the 2nd row of pixels, etc etc.

Comment: Do you need the implementation to be in JavaScript or could it be done server-side?

Comment: On the server I have a rust script that generates the compressed format.  JS needs to decompress it, but I'm really looking for an algorithm here, not a JS implementation.

Comment: Your final goal is interesting. I'd like to know more about it. **(1)** Did I understand this correctly: The compressed seams `3 left left` and `2 right right` should be uncompressed to `3 2 1` and (after the first seam was carved) `2 4 5`? **(2)** Why can the seams only go left and right? Why is a straight vertical seam not possible?

Comment: @Socowi - 1) correct  2) Allowing straight seams yields no visual difference from my testing and the files are 40% larger, so I chose to discard them.  I have all of this working, the only issue is that the decompression step takes about 10 seconds at the moment because I'm literally running `.splice()` 1,000,000 times.  Once it's decompressed I can seam carve images as fast as I can drag them :)  Basically I'm generating an array that is the priority to remove each pixel in each row.  So if I want to rescale a 1000px image to 900px I just run through and filter any values < 100

Answer (score 4):

The simplest O(N log N)-time implementation would probably  be with a Fenwick tree. C++ implementation below.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int NextPowerOfTwo(int n) {
  n |= n >> 1;
  n |= n >> 2;
  n |= n >> 4;
  n |= n >> 8;
  return n + 1;
}

class FenwickTree {
 public:
  explicit FenwickTree(const int n) : sums_(NextPowerOfTwo(n)) {}

  void Add(int index, const int delta) {
    while (index < sums_.size()) {
      sums_[index] += delta;
      index += index & -index;
    }
  }

  int RankQuery(int target) const {
    int index = 0;
    for (int stride = sums_.size() >> 1; stride > 0; stride >>= 1) {
      if (sums_[index + stride] < target) {
        target -= sums_[index + stride];
        index += stride;
      }
    }
    return index + 1;
  }

 private:
  std::vector<int> sums_;
};

std::vector<int> Decompress(const std::vector<int>& splice_indices) {
  const int n = splice_indices.size();
  FenwickTree tree(n);
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) tree.Add(i, 1);
  std::vector<int> result(n);
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    const int j = tree.RankQuery(splice_indices[i - 1]);
    tree.Add(j, -1);
    result[j - 1] = i;
  }
  return result;
}

int main() {
  for (int i : Decompress({3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1})) std::cout << ' ' << i;
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This is also O(n log n) worst (individual) case, right?

Comment: @גלעדברקן indeed.

Answer (score 0):

make 2 new arrays.  Index_old is the same size as your original array, and number it consecutively
index_new starts out empty.  loop through your array with numbers, removing that element from index_old and adding it to the end of index_new

```
index_old[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
index_new[]

//3rd element removed
index_old[1,2,4,5,6,7]
index_new[3]

//1st element removed
index_old[2,4,5,6,7]
index_new[3,1]

//4th element removed
index_old[2,4,5,7]
index_new[3,1,6]

//4th element removed
index_old[2,4,5]
index_new[3,1,6,7]

//3rd element removed
index_old[2,4]
index_new[3,1,6,7,5]

//1st element removed
index_old[4]
index_new[3,1,6,7,5,2]

//1st element removed
index_old[]
index_new[3,1,6,7,5,2,4]
```

then create an index final array of the same size and loop

```
for i= 1 to 7
  final[index_new[i]] = i
```

as it iterates, the loop will populate the final like this

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
[2,0,1,0,0,0,0]
[2,0,1,0,0,3,0]
[2,0,1,0,0,3,4]
[2,0,1,0,5,3,4]
[2,6,1,0,5,3,4]
[2,6,1,7,5,3,4]
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem with this is that it's ***slow***, as splicing an array is O(N) so the whole things is O(N^2)